# Is it possible to delete the file if UnicodeEncodeError occur?

Tags: python-3.x

My code below goes through each .m4v file in the list and converts them to a .wav file using FFmpeg, and it works. I use python 3 jupyter environment.

```
for fpath in list:
    if (fpath.endswith(".m4v")):
        cdir=os.path.dirname(fpath)
        os.chdir(cdir)
        filename=os.path.basename(fpath)
        os.system("ffmpeg -i {0} temp_name.wav".format(filename))
        ofnamepath=os.path.splitext(fpath)[0]
        temp_name=os.path.join(cdir, "temp_name.wav")
        new_name = os.path.join(ofnamepath+'.wav')
        os.rename(temp_name,new_name)
        old_name=os.path.join(ofnamepath+'.m4v')
        os.remove(old_name)
```

However, for this particular dataset I get the following error;

---

```
> UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-10-bd3b17e409fa> in <module>()
>      
> 
> >  7         os.chdir(cdir)
> >       8         filename=os.path.basename(fpath)
> > ----> 9         os.system("ffmpeg -i {0} temp_name.wav".format(filename))
> >      10         ofnamepath=os.path.splitext(fpath)[0]
> >      11         temp_name=os.path.join(cdir, "temp_name.wav")
> 
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position
> 10-16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is it possible to do add an if comment line in the code something like;

```
 if 'UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode'
```

delete that file and continue to the next file?

Comment: why do you want to delete the file? can't you just catch the exception and do nothing in the handler?

Comment: Thanks. I don't have to delete the file. I just don't know how to catch the exception and do nothing in the handler. My python background is not that strong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `try` and `except` block.

If an exception occurs while inside a `try` block, it will jump to the `exception` block. What's better is that you can even specify the exception.

Adding this to your code would look something like:

```py
for fpath in list:
    if (fpath.endswith(".m4v")):
        cdir=os.path.dirname(fpath)
        os.chdir(cdir)
        filename=os.path.basename(fpath)
        try:
            os.system("ffmpeg -i {0} temp_name.wav".format(filename))
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            print("Some failure message.. Continuing to next..")
            # os.remove(filename)
            continue  # This skips the rest of the current iteration and jumps to the top of the loop. 
        ofnamepath=os.path.splitext(fpath)[0]
        temp_name=os.path.join(cdir, "temp_name.wav")
        new_name = os.path.join(ofnamepath+'.wav')
        os.rename(temp_name,new_name)
        old_name=os.path.join(ofnamepath+'.m4v')
        os.remove(old_name)
```

Uncomment the `# os.remove(filename)` to have your files deleted. Are you sure you want to permanently delete them?

Comment: it worked, and I didn`t have to delete the files, thank you so much!